# Аккордеон для списка JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Здравствуйте. Вопрос из разряда фантастики, но все же.

Использую плагин для фильтрации товаров (Themify Product Filter), в графе "фильтрация по категориям" стоит показ иерархии путем небольшого отступа дочерних элементов. Нужно сделать аккордеон для дочерних элементов, при загрузке страницы видны только родительские элементы, при нажатии на него разворачивается список дочерних родителя. Проблема в том, что все категории(и родительские и дочерние) идут одним сплошным списком без каких либо опознавательных знаков(скрин ниже).

Возможно ли каким-то образом это реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

не могли бы вы показать скрин проблемной области на вашем сайте.
зашёл на [офф сайт](https://themify.me/demo/themes/wc-product-filter/product/baller-snapback/)  плагина и не нашёл подобного кода на нём, возможно дело в настройке плагина, либо в параметрах вызова.

В коде зацепиться можно за пробелы. открой тег ли и увидишь разницу между категорией и не категорией перед названием категории.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понимаю просьбу. Этот скрин уже с сайта. В элементах `<li>` уже идут категории

Comment: на фронте это выглядит так https://yadi.sk/i/4EohdvYA3QJCbz

Comment: что то мне подсказывает что это либо не тот участок кода либо это участок кода именно подкатегорий. Так похоже понял. Необходимо цепляться именно к тегу а который вы даже не показали(развернули). Показжите что содержат ваши теги li.

Comment: К сожалению это не только подкатегории. Здесь они никак не подразделяются, ни родительские ни дочерние, а внутри лишь содержимое списка https://yadi.sk/i/WS5pUQ0o3QJDtg

Comment: можете дать линк на сайт или он у вас на локалке? так будет проще разобратся

Comment: Конечно) https://topkidstore.ru/product-category/ever-after-high/